# How to publish document ID?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I am trying to access document `_id` in the client

Here is how I am publishing it:

```
Meteor.publish('events', function () {
        return Requests.find({}, {fields: {"_id": 1, 'start': 1, 'title': 1, 'reasons': 1}});
    });
```

and in the client  when I try to `console.log()` the id, I get "_fc4" printed to the console

Here is my code (in the client):

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(event._id);

        }
```

event is the documents returned. I get the correct value when printing `event.title`, `event.start`, or `event.reasons` to the console. But I get `_fc4` when trying `event._id`.

My question now is, how to publish the `_id` correctly?

**NOTE:** Tried to change `"_id"` with `_id` and received the same results in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your printing the event id in the calendar, not your document in the database.

make sure you set the event id to your document id before adding it to the calendar